# SQLCMD to csv - trailing spaces differs between Windows versions

Tags: csv, sql-server-2005, windows-server-2008, sqlcmd

I use this command for exporting data from SQL Server 2005 to `.csv`:

```
sqlcmd -S (local)\DB -i  c:\Temp\sqlexport\query_trans.sql -o c:\Temp\sqlexport\transactions.csv -W -s ";"
```

which produces the `.csv` file.

The problem I've encountered is that while on Windows 7 this works perfectly, Windows 10 and Windows Server 2008 produce a large amount of trailing spaces in some columns.

How can that functionality differ between Windows versions, and how can I solve it? I already have the -W option as you can see.

Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: This might be explained by differences in behaviour between different versions of sqlcmd. Does `sqlcmd /?` report the same version number on all the machines?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to use a workaround in my SELECT statement

```
SELECT
LTRIM(RTRIM(COLUMNNAME))
```

to make it work.
It would be interesting if someone knew why different windows doesn't trim whitespaces in the csv with -W option